# sorting table using template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have knockout binding on table with columns. I was trying to achieve table sorting for each column.
The view looks like:

```
<table id="notes" class="notes_table">
                            <tr class="head">
                                <th data-bind='click: function() { SortItems("CreatedDate")}'>
                                    <span>Date</span>
                                </th>
                                <th data-bind='click: function() { SortItems("Type")}'>
                                    <span>Type</span>
                                </th>
                                <th data-bind='click: function() { SortItems("Category")}'>
                                    <span>Category</span>
                                </th>
                                <th data-bind='click: function() {SortItems("AddedBy")}'>
                                    <span>Added by</span>
                                </th>
                             </tr>
                            <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'StudentNote', foreach: notes }"></tbody>
                        </table>
                        <script type="text/html" id="StudentNote">
                            <tr class="even">
                                <td><span data-bind="text: CreatedDate"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: Type"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: Category"></span></td>
                                <td><span data-bind="text: AddedBy"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </script>
```

and the javascript is like:

```
function notesViewModel() {
    var _this = {};
    _this.colName = "CreatedDate";
    _this.sortOrder = "desc";
    _this.notes = ko.observableArray();
 _this.SortItems = function (ColumnName) {

        var newNotes = _this.notes();
        if (_this.sortOrder === "desc") {
            this.notes(newNotes.sort(notesViewModel._getSortFunction = function (a, b) {
                _this.sortOrder = "asc";
                return a[ColumnName] < b[ColumnName] ? -1 : 1;
            }));

        } else {
            this.notes(newNotes.sort(notesViewModel._getSortFunction = function (a, b) {
                _this.sortOrder = "desc";
                return a[ColumnName] > b[ColumnName] ? -1 : 1;
            }));
        }
    };
 ko.applyBindings(_this, $("body").get(0));
 return _this;
```

Even though it does sorting, it just switches between ascending and descending sort on each of the column, but not recognises which column it is sorting.. How to do sorting by each column..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function notesViewModel() {
    var _this = {};
    _this.colName = "CreatedDate";
    _this.sortOrder = 1;
    _this.notes = ko.observableArray();
    _this.SortItems = function (ColumnName) {
        if(ColumnName == _this.colName)
            _this.sortOrder = _this.sortOrder * -1;
        else
            _this.colName = ColumnName;

        _this.notes.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a[ColumnName] < b[ColumnName] ? -1 : 1) * _this.sortOrder;
        });
    };
    ko.applyBindings(_this, $("body").get(0));
    return _this;
}
```

Comment: thanks might for reply.. but, if i click on one column and sort them ascending and click on other it sorts the later as descending(means switching between ascending and descending regardless of column)..i expect to see ascending on second column aswell

Comment: I have adjusted the code to retain the sort order when you change columns.

Comment: I have adjusted the code again to meet what I am guessing are your requirements. You may wish to add some more notes to your original question to clarify further exactly how you wish the sorting to work.